# Regex match of email address || a word

Tags: c#, regex, email

I have an input field that will take a keyword input as either an email address or a plain text keyword. I just want to validate that there's no unusual or unsafe characters. My normal validation expression I use for emails on the webform is:

```
"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
```

However, I need an expression that will also take a plain word such as "Blanket". So, I need the expression to take all of the characters of a normal email address but not to validate the sequence that they're in. I've always been horrible at regular expressions. Thanks for your help, Chris.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do this:

```
\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*|\w+
```

`|` means **or**.

So the above regex matches emails or plain words.

Answer (score 4):

> I have an input field that will take a keyword input as either an email address or a plain text keyword.

You shouldn't be trying to validate e-mail addresses using a regexp.

The e-mail address format is covered by *RFC 5322* and if you where to try and write a regexp that goes close to matching that spec, you would need a regexp that looks something like this:

[(((?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*
))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20...(click here to see full regexp)](http://code.iamcal.com/php/rfc822/full_regexp.txt)

The easiest way to validate an e-mail address is to send an e-mail to that address.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the question

```
\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]*)
```

i hope this be helpful